# Stack or use multiple notification toasts

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, notification, toast

I’ve seen it many times before where you’re on a website and you get a notification which comes in the form of a toast, if you perform the same action another toast will appear and it will push the previous toast slightly up the screen.

I’m wondering, would it be better to have multiple toasts displaying or whether it would be better that if another one got triggered, remove the previous one as soon as possible and enter the new one?

Comment: Hi @tallent123, thanks for your contribution to UXSE. Do you have any screenshots of the example that you have seen for reference? From your own perspective, which option do you think works better and why?

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting read from https://www.nngroup.com about notifications, indicators and validations.

> > In interaction design, a system should always keep users informed, by providing appropriate feedback. Ensuring that the state of the system is always visible is one of the 10 usability heuristics for interface design. (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/indicators-validations-notifications/)

Notifications are focused on system-related events. In this case if its **passive notifications** one can show notification toasts as stacked pile with option to dismiss each, as well as setting up time for each notification toast to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple toasts would be better. I personally get frustrated with sites that do not clearly differentiate between older toast messages and newer ones. 
They always make me go "Is this a toast for my older action or the new one? How long should I wait for this older toast to go away so that I can retry the action and be sure that its for the newer one?"

Answer (score 0):

**stacking toast notifications seem fine to me.** actually toast are temporary UI elements which go away after a little delay (between 3 and 6 seconds usually). so stacking them is not a big distraction for users.